# How to break chart links of charts pasted in ppt from excel without losing data?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I have to paste multiple charts from an excel file which is very heavy (>10MB) and having excel-linked charts makes the presentation heavy too. Can we create a macro which enables us to relink charts in ppt to original excel charts, update chart data and break link to keep the file size down.

We basically do a lot of iterations to model inputs in the last few days before sending out the deck to the client and want to avoid wasting time in repasting/reformatting/updating charts in ppt from excel.

The mentioned code enables me to break chart links to excel and reduce the ppt file size however the charts dont remain editable after this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
Sub BreakChartLinks()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasChart Then
        shp.LinkFormat.BreakLink
        End If
    Next shp
Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: With a linked Excel Chart the PowerPoint should not grown heavy. But the heavy Excel Workbook is needed to be accessible.

Comment: So why there is no UI-possibility to copy the Excel Chart and paste it as a PowerPoint Chart but only as a Excel Chart (linked or not) again or as a picture? Because the Excel Chart could get its data dependent from all the Sheets in the Workbook. So the whole heavy Workbook is needed. Copy only the Chart and the for this Chart really needed Sheets into a new Workbook. This new Workbook should then not be so heavy. Copy and paste then from this new Workbook into PowerPoint as not linked Excel Chart.

Comment: Thanks for this Alex. However, I have over 50 charts in the workbook that have to be pasted in the ppt so it would be very cumbersome to manually copy chart data in a new workbook everytime. Also, I need to do the same exercise repeatedly for each iteration in the model inputs. Thus I need a macro enabled solution to reduce time spent on redundant exercises. I have found a couple of standalone codes which if/when combined should provide a partial solution to my problem.

Comment: (cont'd from above)...these codes are ---- 1) Code to update links for various charts; and 2) Code to extract data from a chart with broken/bad links. I now need to find a way to convert a chart pasted from excel into a ppt chart (with data) and back to excel pasted chart. IT would be great if you could help me with that.

Comment: All what I have described is possible with VBA in Excel. But "convert a chart pasted from excel into a ppt chart (with data) and back to excel pasted chart" is not possible, as far as I know. So make your own effort with VBA in Excel and ask special questions if you are stuck.